# HTML form Post to email address with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, post, frontend

Hi there im building a website and looking to connect a contact form to send an email/ message to an email address and im not quite sure what im doing wrong.

I'm very new so apologies and thank you in advance..

here's the code i have below!

PHP

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mailTo = 'tomasyoung0@gmail.com';
  $headers = 'From: '.$mailFrom;
  $txt = 'You have received an e-mail from '.$name.'. \n\n'.$message;

  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
  header('Location: index.html?mailsend')



?>
```

HTML

```
<form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="POST">
      
      <input class="form-input" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" >
      <input class="form-input" name="email"  type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input class="form-input" name="subject"  type="text" placeholder="Subject" >
      <textarea class="form-input" placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <button class="btn"type="submit" name="submit">
        <div class="button">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><span class="send-text"></span>
        </div>
      
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: One thing I can spot is that you're reading `$_POST['mail']` while your input is named `email`, not `mail`.

Comment: Why textarea don't have name?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have mail and message at your html code, change

```
<input class="form-input" name="email"  type="email" placeholder="Email">
```

To

```
<input class="form-input" name="mail"  type="email" placeholder="Email">
```

And

```
<textarea class="form-input" placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea class="form-input" name = "message" placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Inside [] of post variable you must put name of your input or button inside [] using ''